# How to disable Code Completion in Android Studio?

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-studio

I am new in Android Programming and I want to disable the auto-completion in Android studio. I think this might even improve my coding ability and help me to understand the API Structure. I've done a lot of search in Google, but nothing found positive. So how to disable the `auto-completion` in Android Studio ? I want disable code-completion of every language (`XML`,`JAVA`,`Groovy`...).

**I want to show nothing even if I press the <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>space</kbd> .**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Go to **File-> Setting-> Editor** unchecked all check box

[image]

Then Go to **File-> Setting-> Keymap-> Main Menu->Code->Completion** remove all hot keys and apply.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

File -> Power Saver Mode

This disables a bunch of features, including code completion

Comment: but it's still showing suggestions after pressing the Control+Space. :( . and i think it'll also disable the lint, but i want my lint alive.

Comment: I may have missed it, but I didn't see that requirement in the initial question

Comment: oh sorry! i've  missed to add that requirement.

Comment: Thanks, this is a quick and easy option for temporarily disabling code completion, for example when editing lots of variable names.

Answer (score 1):

Go to

**File-> Setting-> Editor**

unchecked all check box

[image]

then

Go to **Keymap-> type basic** in search box

Then Under
 **Main Menu-> Code -> Completion-> select Basic ->Right click ->remove Ctrl+Space**

assign

**Ctrl+Space to any other option**

[image]

Comment: but it's still showing suggestions after pressing the `Control+Space`. :( . I want complete disable.

Comment: I think there is a option `Basic Completion (Ctrl+Space)` if you uncheck that it will not show.

Comment: Restarted 2 times, still the code completion is working.

Comment: I got a working answer from @AhmadNawaz , you said you found something,what was that ?